# i am wondering if i can hook up 2 video cards (SLI ready)

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

okay so right now i have this card http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8869861
i want to get a 2nd video card maybe this one
http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8379339&csid=_61&rrpl=item_page.content1&rrstr=ClickCP&rrindex=3
will these two work together? i have a crosshair formula z mothe board and a amd 9570. now that i have the crosshair and its rog i can use multipule video cards im mainly just wondering if these two cards will work together. 
thanks

Comment: whoops i meant 9590 sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use both cards in your system at the same time. However, not connected to each other. One is crossfire compatible, while the other is SLI compatible. You can choose how to orient them and decide which one going to be your main GPU, while the other will essentially serve as a PhysX card (760).